How to set GOARCH in App Engine deployment
My app is written in Google Go and I deploy to the standard environment in the App Engine,
for this app (due to how floating points work differently from AMD64 and ARM64) it is important to build specifically for ARM64.
On my local machine I can just set GOARCH=ARM64 build flag.
How can I set this flag for deploying in App Engine? Is it possible to set this in app.yaml?

IIRC App Engine standard provides only AMD64 (there are no ARM64) instance types
